# Redirecting from one route to another in my laravel 4 and angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, redirect, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am building an using laravel4 and angular at the front end. After submit data from a form I want to redirect to another route but I do not know how to exactly do this since I submit data using angular $http service. The route is already defined in laravel, but how do I redirect? Please some guide me through thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess when your form is being submitted, it goes through a controller class like `SubmitFormController`. There you could simply redirect like this:

```
return Redirect::to('home');
```

If you're wondering how to redirect to a page with javascript:

```
window.location.href = 'home';
```

Maybe I'm not understanding your question. In that case please clearify your question.